# Entity Framework DbGeography not calculating the Area correctly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, gis, postgis

If I define the polygon in WKT format as this (longitude/latitude):

```
string wkt = "POLYGON ((15.981800258159638 45.810693408924287, 15.983624160289764 45.810783148865241, 15.983688533306122 45.809844611497965, 15.981843173503876 45.8096838246252, 15.981800258159638 45.810693408924287))"
```

and I create the `DbGeography` object as this:

```
var polygon = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(wkt);
```

the value of the `Area` property is 510065621695499.69

If I do the same thing using Postgres and PostGis like this:

```
select ST_Area(ST_GeographyFromText(wkt))
```

the result is 15496.7483872527 which should be the correct value.

If I create the polygon by reversing coordinates (latitude/longitude), both `DbGeography` and `ST_Area` return the same value (21247.6269483712)

Can anybody explain what is going on here?

PS: the polygon is located in Zagreb, Croatia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to do with **polygon orientation**. For these spatial data types, "The interior of the polygon in an ellipsoidal system is defined by the left-hand rule", to quote [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx).  See eg [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4409922/71059) and no doubt many others for further reading and approaches to address this.

If you **reverse the order** of the points in your WKT, you will get an area `15496.7447813973` (using a [SRID of 4326 corresponding to WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID)), which is very close to what your other GIS systems are giving you. The difference I would guess might be due to a different SRID, but I'm far from an expert.

Note that the erroneous result you are getting is very close to 510,072,000 km², the surface area of the entire Earth - since `DbGeography` uses the orientation protocol it does, it has constructed the *outside* of the polygon you intended.

Answer (score 1):

To add to AakashM 's answer, if you always want the smaller area you can do this:

```
    public double GetArea(string wellKnownText)
    {
        var sqlGeo = SqlGeography.Parse(wellKnownText);
        var normalArea = sqlGeo.STArea().Value;
        var reorientedArea = sqlGeo.ReorientObject().STArea().Value;
        // just trying to not return almost the whole area of our beloved planet...
        return Math.Min(normalArea, reorientedArea);
    }
```