# Finding shortest distance between two polygons(SqlGeography c# )

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, spatial

I want to find the shortest distance between two SqlGeography polygon. I know there is a method `ShortestLineTo` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929252.aspx) but it gives empty string while doing so.
Can anyone suggest me some alternate way to do so?
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code sample?

Comment: added sample. Please look at the image.

Comment: provide you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a `GEOGRAPHY` in Counter Clockwise order. If you define it CW, it will be all the world except the region you are defining:

```sql
DECLARE @G1 GEOGRAPHY = 'POLYGON ((1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 1))';
DECLARE @G2 GEOGRAPHY = 'POLYGON ((45 45, 45 46, 44 46, 44 45, 45 45))';

//This is what you have defined
DECLARE @G3 GEOGRAPHY = 'POLYGON ((45 45, 44 45, 44 46, 45 46, 45 45))';
```

**@G1**: point order is **CCW** so @G1 is a polygon containing `POINT(2,2)`

**@G2**: point order is **CCW** so @G2 is a polygon containing `POINT(44.5,45.5)`

**@G3**: point order is **CW** so @G3 is a polygon containing the *entire world* except the @G2 polygon. It also contains the @G1 polygon, so the shortest distance between @G1 and @G3 doesn't have any meaning.

#### Toggle Between CW and CCW geometries

Using the [`ReorientObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929311.aspx) method, you can toggle between CW and CCW geographies. So if you try:

```sql
SELECT @G3.ReorientObject().STDifference(@G2).STAsText();
```

The result would be `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY` because they contain the same region. So they intersect and the result of `ShortestLineTo` returns a `LINESTRING EMPTY` because they intersect each other.

#### One more point

You can check if a polygon contains too large of a region by checking the [`EnvelopeAngle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645617.aspx) so you are made aware of mistakenly defined geographies.

[image: Envelope angle demonstration screenshot]

As shown in the picture, `EnvelopeAngle=180` means that polygon contains a very large region of the world.

Comment: @messi glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Use ShortestLineTo

> An empty LineString instance is returned when the two geography
>   instances intersect each other.

Comment: Problem is that two geography instances are not intersecting. See the image to get a clarity.

Comment: @messi they do intersect, So LeMara is pointing to the correct issue but for more explanation you may look at my answer.