# Find If 4 Points Form a Quadrilateral

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Can someone please show me an algorithm to write a function that returns true if 4 points form a quadrilateral, and false otherwise? The points do not come with any order.

I've tried to check all permutations of the 4 points and see if there's 3 points that forms a straight line. If there's 3 points that forms a straight line than it's not quadrilateral. But then I realize that there's no way to tell the order. And then I struggle for several hours of thinking and googling with no result :(

I've read these questions:

1. [find if 4 points on a plane form a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303278/find-if-4-points-on-a-plane-form-a-rectangle)
2. [Determining ordering of vertices to form a quadrilateral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009548/determining-ordering-of-vertices-to-form-a-quadrilateral)

But still find no solution. In the case of 1, it can't detect another kind of quadrilateral, and in 2 it assumes that the points are quadirateral already. Are there any other way to find out if 4 points form a quadirateral?

Thanks before.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

I define quadrilateral as simple quadrilateral, basically all shapes shown in this picture:
[image: Quadirateral]

except the shape with "quadrilateral" and "complex" caption.

As for problems with the "checking for collinear triplets" approach, I tried to check the vertical, horizontal, and diagonal lines with something like this:

```
def is_linear_line(pt1, pt2, pt3):
    return (pt1[x] == pt2[x] == pt3[x] ||
            pt1[y] == pt2[y] == pt3[y] ||
            slope(pt1, pt2) == slope(pt2, pt3))
```

And realize that rectangle and square will count as linear line since the slope of the points will be all the same. Hope this clears things out.

Comment: How do you define a quadrilateral? And please explain what's wrong with checking for collinear triplets in more detail.

Comment: @tom: I've edited the question for clarifications. Please tell me if something's still unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. According do this definition, any four points form a quadrilateral if you can choose the edges.

Comment: @tom is right. The question should be "if 4 points **can** form a quadrilateral".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for checking if a quadrilateral is convex. Not if it is a simple quadrilateral.

I did like this in objective-c https://github.com/hfossli/AGGeometryKit/

```
extern BOOL AGQuadIsConvex(AGQuad q)
{
    BOOL isConvex = AGLineIntersection(AGLineMake(q.bl, q.tr), AGLineMake(q.br, q.tl), NULL);
    return isConvex;
}

BOOL AGLineIntersection(AGLine l1, AGLine l2, AGPoint *out_pointOfIntersection)
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/202451

    AGPoint p = l1.start;
    AGPoint q = l2.start;
    AGPoint r = AGPointSubtract(l1.end, l1.start);
    AGPoint s = AGPointSubtract(l2.end, l2.start);

    double s_r_crossProduct = AGPointCrossProduct(r, s);
    double t = AGPointCrossProduct(AGPointSubtract(q, p), s) / s_r_crossProduct;
    double u = AGPointCrossProduct(AGPointSubtract(q, p), r) / s_r_crossProduct;

    if(t < 0 || t > 1.0 || u < 0 || u > 1.0)
    {
        if(out_pointOfIntersection != NULL)
        {
            *out_pointOfIntersection = AGPointZero;
        }
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        if(out_pointOfIntersection != NULL)
        {
            AGPoint i = AGPointAdd(p, AGPointMultiply(r, t));
            *out_pointOfIntersection = i;
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine both vertex order and presence of a quadrilateral in the same operation unless you use operations that are far more expensive than what you're already performing.

Comment: the expensiveness of the operation is not a concern. Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 1):

Checking for collinear triplets (like you did) will exclude cases where the four points form triangles  or  straight lines.

To exclude also the complex quadrilateral (with crossing edges):

A quadrilateral formed by the points A, B, C and D is complex, if the intersection of AB and CD (if any) lies between the points A and B, and the same applies for BC and DA.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any more inputs than the 4 points? because if 4 points succeed to your test, they can always form 3 different quadrilaterals, sometime of different family. For example, Take a square, add 2 diagonal and remove the side.

So with only 4 points as input, you cannot do better than what you are already doing.

Comment: Nope, there's only 4 inputs. There's no more way to improve it then?

Comment: Although I am a decade late, but any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Let A, B, C and D be the four points. You have to assume that the edges are A-B, B-C, C-D, and D-A. If you can't make that assumption, the four points will always form a quadrilateral.

```java
if (A-B intersects C-D) return false
if (B-C intersects A-D) return false
return true
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find all side and diagonal sizes using the distance formula:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBBRA.png).

Next, find all angles using this formula:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd3xt.png)

reference from: https://algorithmdotcpp.blogspot.com/2022/01/find-type-of-quadrilateral-with-given-points.html

Code in python:

```py
    # array
    # read 8 number
    points = list(map(int,input().split()))    

    # create separate variable for coordinates
    xa = points[0]
    ya = points[1]
    xb = points[2]
    yb = points[3]
    xc = points[4]
    yc = points[5]
    xd = points[6]
    yd = points[7]

    # edge of quadrilateral using edge formula
    # finding edge using distance formula.
    a = math.sqrt((xb - xa) * (xb - xa) + (yb - ya) * (yb - ya))
    b = math.sqrt((xc - xb) * (xc - xb) + (yc - yb) * (yc - yb))
    c = math.sqrt((xd - xc) * (xd - xc) + (yd - yc) * (yd - yc))
    d = math.sqrt((xa - xd) * (xa - xd) + (ya - yd) * (ya - yd))

    # diagonal of quadrilateral
    # find diagonals.
    diagonal_ac = math.sqrt((xc - xa) * (xc - xa) + (yc - ya) * (yc - ya))
    diagonal_bd = math.sqrt((xd - xb) * (xd - xb) + (yd - yb) * (yd - yb))

    # angles
    # angles of quadrilateral
    # find angle using angle formula.
    A = math.acos((a * a + d * d - diagonal_bd * diagonal_bd) / (2 * a * d))
    B = math.acos((b * b + a * a - diagonal_ac * diagonal_ac) / (2 * b * a))
    C = math.acos((c * c + b * b - diagonal_bd * diagonal_bd) / (2 * c * b))
    D = math.acos((d * d + c * c - diagonal_ac * diagonal_ac) / (2 * d * c))
```

Now we can determine whether the type of quadrilateral or quadrilateral is not found using if-else conditions.

```py
    # if angles are equal means(90*)
    if (A == B and A == C and A == D):
    
        # if edge size are equal
        if (a == b and a == c and a == d):
            # square
            print("Quadrilateral is square...\n")
            print("area of square :", a * a)
        
        # else
        else:
            # rectangular
            print("Quadrilateral is rectangular...\n")
            print("area of square :", a * b)
        
    
    # angles are not equal but edges are equal
    elif (a == b and a == c and a == d):
        # diamond
        print("Quadrilateral is diamond(Rhombus)...\n")
    
    # opposite edges(sides) are equal
    elif (a == c and b == d):
        # parallelogram
        print("Quadrilateral is parallelogram...")
    
    else:
        print("Quadrilateral is just a quadrilateral...\n")
```