# ordering points of a contour

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I detected a rectangle by:

1. finding contours
2. approximating polygon

then I tried to find the corners of the rectangle as:

```
imgPoints[0]=contours_poly[i][0];  
imgPoints[1]=contours_poly[i][1];  
imgPoints[3]=contours_poly[i][3];  
imgPoints[2]=contours_poly[i][2];
```

I want to order these points in a predefined order due to a reference point. Let's say I want to start at point 0, how can I order the
previous points?

Answer (score 3):

If you calculate vectors from point `0` to point `x` and `y`, their [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) will which tell you vector is more counter-clockwise.

The code sample [was given in the question "Sort four points in the clockwise order"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/242509/13767).